# Extracting text notes from an iOS 5 backup file?

Tags: itunes, ios, backup, ipod

So, I have backuped my ipod touch ios 5, and downgraded to iOS 4.1 (the only with SHSH available)

Now i can't restore my backup to iOS 4...

I am only interested to my notes, do I have anyway to extract them from my backup? (itunes, windows)

Answer (score 4):

Ok I did it with iPhone Back Extractor. Lucky me the first note was that I needed

Download the free edition here: http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/free-download/

It will locate automatically your backup folder otherwise you can select it manually, then select what you want to extract.

So, download the app, run it and then select your backup, if it has not been already found by the application itself. Then, the simplest way is to click the blue number next to 'Notes' in the available data section. You can also extract your Notes to .HTML format using the 'Extract' menu and choosing 'Notes as HTML'. You can do that for contacts, photos, calendar, location data, call history and so on.

Comment: Might you expand this to link to the tool and summarize the tidbit or note so that people here can understand how you overcome this issue without needing to read an entire linked article?